# Eclipse eGit : History view only shows local history, not remote history

Tags: eclipse, git, history, egit

I used to be able to see the actual commit history of a file, but now all I get is the local history:

[image]

What has changed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open **Git Repositories** view by clicking `Windows > Show View > Git Repositories`.

Select your repository in this view. Right click on it then select `Show In > History` option.

If you want to the history of a given file(Ex: server.js as shown in the image in question). Select/Locate this file in **Package explorer/Navigator/Project Explorer** view then right click on this file then select `Team > Show in History` option.

Comment: I think that worked... not sure, since now I can't get back to this "local history" view.

Comment: What if there is no Team > Show in History option? How do you get that? I used to have it but after downloading and installing newest eclipse-java-kepler-SR2-macosx-cocoa-x86_64, I can' get it anymore.

Comment: @user2568374 Post it as a separate question. Chained discussion threads are NOT encouraged in stackoverflow.

Comment: What's the difference between "chained discussion" and asking a specific question on an answer provided that is directly related to the answer?

Comment: @user2568374: I had the same problem and was able to fix it by right clicking the project in the project explorer and going to Team -> Share Project.

Answer (score 1):

To solve this problem, I only had to click on the most right button in the history view, named "Show All Branches and Tags", shown below that is the two arrows pointing down after splitting.

The master branch was a few commits ahead and didn't show if that was not "on".

[image: The two arrows pointing down]

Answer (score 0):

I came across this post while having the same probelm and searching for a solution. What helped in my case was the comment from @jazzpi to @Chandrayya G K's answer:

Right-click on the project and choose "**Team -> Share Project**"

After doing this the History always shows the git history instead of the local history. And it is not necessary to always right-click on a file and navigate to "Team -> Show in History". Furthermore, only after that, the button described by @Jonathan Drapeau appears ("Show All Branches and Tags").

Answer (score -1):

It works even if you have a git Project: Right click in the "Package Explorer" or "Project Explorer" on your file. Choose the option "Compare With"-> "Local History..."

[image]

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question, and there's already an accepted answer.